# Download link . select tag a by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, asp.net-ajax

One: `a.txt` a file contains HTML;

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="downloadLink" ="~/Download/a.txt" runat="server">downloadLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

When I click on the `downloadLink` The file will be downloaded. But this code shows the files content in the browser.

If the tag number a 3 How can we have. When clicking on each one will give it to us href;

```
 <a href="k1">kp1</a>
 <a href="k2">kp2</a>
 <a href="k3">kp3</a>
```

when click on kp1 alert me k1 and when click on kp2 alert me k2 and...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the second part of your question correctly (I cannot make sense of the first part), you want something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        window.alert($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but does this do what your looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ememV/1/

Answer (score 0):

For your first point, you want to create a proxy .aspx page that loads your text file and serves it back after setting the `ContentType` to something like `application/octet-stream`:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
  string FilePath = MapPath("~/Download/a.txt"); // or you can read
                                                 // it from Request.Form
  Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
  Response.End();
}
```

Alternatively, set the `.txt` content type in IIS to `application/octet-stream`.

For the second, something as simple as this would work:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href');
    return false; // to prevent the redirect
  });
});
```

Note however that storing data in `href` is a pretty bad idea. Use `title` or a custom attribute instead.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.